# Нужен скрипт для автоматизаций подключений к пк

Tags: python, powershell

Нужен скрипт для автоматизаций подключений к пк, иммитировать win+r \\johnPC Можно это как то реализовать, с помощью python или PowerShell ??

Answer (score 1):

1. Создайте текстовый файл
2. Добавьте в него строку, где `NamePC` это путь до папки устройства

```
explorer \\NamePC
```

3. Сохраните файл с расширением `.bat` вместо `.txt`